# Regular expression to remove everything except links for notepad++ or regex101.com

Tags: regex, url, notepad++

So i've tried this multiple times but to no avail.

I have a code where I need to remove everything except links. The domain can be any domain, either http or https

```
/**/
  
 jQuery(function($){
  playerInit( 11403, 'Убийца Богов', 'json', [{"id":"0","title":" 176","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/176.mp3","error":0,"duration":909,"duration_min":"15:09"},{"id":"1","title":" 177","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/177.mp3","error":0,"duration":850,"duration_min":"14:10"},{"id":"2","title":" 178","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/178.mp3","error":0,"duration":800,"duration_min":"13:20"},{"id":"3","title":" 179","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/179.mp3","error":0,"duration":834,"duration_min":"13:54"},{"id":"4","title":" 180","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/180.mp3","error":0,"duration":898,"duration_min":"14:58"},{"id":"5","title":" 181","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/181.mp3","error":0,"duration":777,"duration_min":"12:57"},{"id":"6","title":" 182","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/182.mp3","error":0,"duration":832,"duration_min":"13:52"},{"id":"7","title":" 183","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/183.mp3","error":0,"duration":827,"duration_min":"13:47"},{"id":"8","title":" 184","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/184.mp3","error":0,"duration":837,"duration_min":"13:57"},{"id":"9","title":" 185","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/185.mp3","error":0,"duration":809,"duration_min":"13:29"},{"id":"10","title":" 186","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/186.mp3","error":0,"duration":853,"duration_min":"14:13"},{"id":"11","title":" 187","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/187.mp3","error":0,"duration":860,"duration_min":"14:20"},{"id":"12","title":" 188","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/188.mp3","error":0,"duration":881,"duration_min":"14:41"},{"id":"13","title":" 189","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/189.mp3","error":0,"duration":815,"duration_min":"13:35"},{"id":"14","title":" 190","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/190.mp3","error":0,"duration":720,"duration_min":"12:00"},{"id":"15","title":" 191","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/191.mp3","error":0,"duration":757,"duration_min":"12:37"},{"id":"16","title":" 192","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/192.mp3","error":0,"duration":873,"duration_min":"14:33"},{"id":"17","title":" 193","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/193.mp3","error":0,"duration":801,"duration_min":"13:21"},{"id":"18","title":" 194","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/194.mp3","error":0,"duration":902,"duration_min":"15:02"},{"id":"19","title":" 195","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/195.mp3","error":0,"duration":830,"duration_min":"13:50"},{"id":"20","title":" 196","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/196.mp3","error":0,"duration":820,"duration_min":"13:40"},{"id":"21","title":" 197","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/197.mp3","error":0,"duration":968,"duration_min":"16:08"},{"id":"22","title":" 198","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/198.mp3","error":0,"duration":790,"duration_min":"13:10"},{"id":"23","title":" 199","url":"https://ii-z.ru/11403/199.mp3","error":0,"duration":790,"duration_min":"13:10"}], 'https://audiokniga.one/uploads/posts/2023-11/1699047567_1-1.webp');
 });
 
/**/
```

**At the end I need to get a list of links, each from a new line**

```
  https://ii-z.ru/11403/177.mp3
  https://ii-z.ru/11403/178.mp3
  https://ii-z.ru/11403/179.mp3
```

I hope someone can help me.

I have code that highlights all the links along with the sign, but I don't know how to save them and cut out the sign

```
  https?:\/\/.*?[\s+"]
```

Comment: Why implement this using a text editor when command line tools are much better suited for it?  `grep -oE ' https?:\/\/[^\s+"]+' my-file.html`  https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NB: Position the cursor at the very begining of the file

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"url":"([^"]+)"|.`
- Replace with: `(?1$1\n)`
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"url":"         # literally
([^"]+)         # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a double quote
"               # double quote
  |               # OR
.               # any character
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists
    $1          # print it
    \n          # line feed, you can use \r\n for Windows
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]